# Saving model's data in the model vs an external data manager class

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have a bunch of models (using activejdbc) Person, Company, Health, .... etc (I have 8 models). I'm showing an example of just one model Person

In the first approach I have a data manager that handles all my insertions to my various models, for example for Person I have

```
public class Person extends Model {
    static {
        validatePresenceOf(“name”, “birthdate”);
    }
}
```

and in the Data Manager I do the insertion

```
public class DataManager {
    private DBManager dbManager;
    public void insertData(Data data) throws Exception {
        try {
            dbManager.openActiveJDBCBaseConnection();
            insertPerson(data)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // stuff
        } finally {
            dbManager.closeActiveJDBCBaseConnection();
        }
    }
   public void insertPerson(Data data) {
       Person person = new Person();
       person.set(“name”, data.name);
       person.set(“birthdata”, data.birthdata);
       person.set(“country”, data.country();
       person.saveit();
}
```

Versus doing the actual insertion from the person model itself using a static method and then calling it from the data manager

```
public class Person extends Model {
    static {
        validatePresenceOf(“name”, “birthdate”);
    }
    public static void insertPerson(PersonData data) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.set(“name”, data.name);
        person.set(“birthdata”, data.birthdata);
        person.set(“country”, data.country();
        person.saveit();
    }

}

public class DataManager {
    private DBManager dbManager;
    public void insertPerson(PersonData data) throws Exception {
        try {
        dbManager.openActiveJDBCBaseConnection();
            Person.insertPerson(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // stuff
        } finally {
            dbManager.closeActiveJDBCBaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is better?

Comment: I have the same structure for my get queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the first example you've given is the best. It seems to adhere more to the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). What this basically means is that your classes should only one responsibility.

*Note: You're actually still breaking the principle, because I think activeJDBC requires objects to save themselves? (I'm not experienced with activeJDBC, but after looking around a little it seems that this is the way it's done). For example `Person.saveit()` isn't really a great solution in my opinion, but we'll ignore that.*

The reason why I would prefer the first example is because it makes a lot more sense to use something called a `DataManager` for insertions, than a `Person` class.

If you look the the second example `Person.insertPerson()` just really doesn't make much sense. Does a `Person` really insert a person? In my opinion you should stick as close to reality as possible (of course there are exceptions), and letting a person insert a person doesn't really reflect reality. `Person.sit()` or `Person.eat()` is something I would expect to find in a `Person` class.

A `DataManager` (what's in a name) indicates that it manages data. And at first thought I could assume/think that this would be used for inserting/receiving/updating objects (if I hadn't inspected the code). Saying `DataManager.insertPerson()` seems like the more logical solution for me (even though it still has to actually use `Person.saveit()` for it to actually insert/save the object).

**TL;DR** I guess you're question could be put as "*Should I save a model's data in the model or in an external data manager class?*". My answer to this would be use the external data manager class (`DataManager`). Just because it makes more sense to have a data manager have an `insertPerson()` method, than an actual model have that method.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of ActiveJDBC.

I built quite a few projects with JavaLite over the past years, and the following pattern emerged:

```
public class Person extends Model {
   public static Person createPerson(String name, Date birthDate, String country) {
      return Person.createIt("name", name, "birthdate", birthDate, "country", country);
   }
}
```

Generally, we completely avoid building intermediary classes like your `PersonData` because it just duplicates code for no good reason. We also do not build so-called managers because ActiveJDBC models know how to take care of themselves.

In other words, if the access to a table requires some logic, we would build a static method on a model class. In some cases though, such a method might manage more than one model. If it gets to complicated, this code is migrated to one level up - to a service class for orchestration.

This approach served us well, building applications with schemas ranging from 50 to 200 tables. The simpler the approach, the easier the maintenance.